# external js not loading

Tags: javascript, external

I'm trying to get this codepen code working locally:

http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mCdbD/

However, when I try to load the js as an external script, it does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

<script src="isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="isotopes.js"></script>
```

But if I copy paste the file into the markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
  // quick search regex
  var qsRegex;
  var buttonFilter;

  // init Isotope
  var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    filter: function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
      var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
      return searchResult && buttonResult;
    }
  });

  $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    buttonFilter = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope();
  });

  // use value of search field to filter
  var $quicksearch = $('#quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
    qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
    $container.isotope();
  }) );


    // change is-checked class on buttons
  $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
    });
  });


});

// debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
  var timeout;
  return function debounced() {
    if ( timeout ) {
      clearTimeout( timeout );
    }
    function delayed() {
      fn();
      timeout = null;
    }
    setTimeout( delayed, threshold || 100 );
  };
}
</script>

<link rel = "stylesheet" type= "text/css"  href = "style.css">

<h1>Isotope - filtering with search field and button filters</h1>...
```

Then it does work sometimes. Could someone explain how to get the external js file loading?

Comment: your html and js files are in the same directory?

Comment: According to Inspect Element source code, you don't have any included files...

Comment: I see a `<head>` tag with just a title and CSS... looks like all your scripts are in `<body>`?

Comment: @raumaankidwai are you inspecting the source of the codepen?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? That will help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: Yes I am inspecting the console, the iframe to be specific.

Comment: @raumaankidwai My understanding is that he has it all as one "file" in codepen, and when he separates them for local work, it does not work.

Comment: @sharf agreed. Can OP please give some more info?

Answer (score -1):

The type attribute is required in HTML 4.01 (source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp).

`<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>`

Comment: Based on his `DOCTYPE` it appears he is using HTML5